# How to properly set width and height of SVG in javascript?

Tags: svg

I am setting the width and height of a SVG image in javascript and it does not work. My code is like this:

```
var url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74728667/left_arrow.svg";
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('get', url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev)
        {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4)
            {
                if (xhr.status === 200)
                {
                     var e = xhr.responseXML.documentElement;
                var svg = document.importNode(e, true); 
                svg.setAttribute("width", "28px");
                svg.setAttribute("height", "28px");
            svg.style.border="1px solid black";
            svg.style.position="absolute";
            svg.style.left="50px";
            svg.style.top="50px";
            main.appendChild(svg);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("request failed");
                }
            }           
        };
        xhr.send();
```

Above code produces a result like this:

[image]

Note the SVG is not resized to the specified width and height. **how can i fix this?**. i have tried using `svg.setAttributeNS(null, "width", "28px");`

I inspected the resulting html produced by above code and if I copy paste it in a separate [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siddjain/VW56K/), I get this:

HTML:

```
<div id="main" style="position:relative"><svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 18 18" width="28px" height="28px" style="border: 1px solid black; position: absolute; left: 50px; top: 50px;">
    <path fill="#a00" fill-opacity="1" stroke="none" d="M 0,9 l 17,9 -6,-9 6,-9 Z" onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('fill', '#ac0');" onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('fill','#a00');"></path>
</svg></div>
```

Output:

[image]

How can I make my js code produce the same result as above?

Comment: Set value to viewBox attribute of svg element.

Comment: viewBox is already specified in the svg file.

Comment: Not view"b"ox, view"B"ox is right. Stand alone svg file is sensitive to spell of attribute name.

Comment: yes, this was indeed the problem! the fiddle works now. if you post your comment as answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probrem is caused by spell miss of view"b"ox in source svg file.
Web browser doesn't treat view"b"ox attribute as view"B"ox attribute, because stand alone svg file is xml file.
Thus you should correct the svg source like this.

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 18 18"
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 18 18"
```

But these attributes are treated as same at inline svg in html. 
This act is defined by HTML parsing rule, see this.
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#creating-and-inserting-nodes